# email experience manager sitecore email bounce list report

Tags: email, sitecore, reporting, sitecore8

im using exm version 3.1, my csv has 12000 recepients but with only 2 email correct. I send the email, but in the exm report says the actual recepients is 12000 and my bounce list still empty. is it exm behavior or do i have to set something in sitecore?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw3VE.png)

Comment: Do all other xDB reports work correctly?

Comment: yea, the unsubscribe list, Best Email Landing Pages list, Email Landing Page Performance reports all work correctly and always updating its data. Only email bounce list didnt work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work of bounce detection have list of thing that are not obvious when you [try to use it](http://sitecorevn.blogspot.co.uk/2016/07/sitecore-exm-in-depth-hard-and-soft.html).

What version of ExM do you use? If it is lower than 3.3 then you should use delivery via AppCenter for ability to detect bounce messages.

If you use ExM 3.3 then follow [this article](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/message_transfer_agent/delivery_status_notifications) to setup receiving of delivery status notifications.

Comment: hi anton thank you, im using exm version 3.1 and fyi im new to exm-sitecore, so i kinda confused about it. So if i didnt subscribe delivery email service in via app center that means i will not get report email bounce on exm report and on engagement plan report the email failed percentage will always 0%? and that email bounce list will always empty?

Comment: Yes. To get bounce value in your report you should either subscribe to email delivery service in AppCenter or upgrade to ExM 3.3 and configure status delivery notifications.